# jQuery validate. only required with specific option

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to validate if there is any text in the custom field but only if the custom option is selected above. I'm very new to HTML (alright with C) so please excuse the rest of my mistakes (probably many) but please point them out with an explanation :)
I have tried following the other questions people have posted here with very similar situations but not making any progress.
Thank you!

```html
        <html lang="en">
        <main>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     
  <h1>D D D S </h1>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="request.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  jQuery(function ($) {
  $('#myInput').validate({
   debug: true,
   rules: {
        customdrinkfield: {
            required: function (el) {
                return $(el).closest('form').find('.drinkChoice').val() == 'custom'; } }
   }
  });
        });   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function checkvalue(val) {
     var element=document.getElementById('çustomdrinkfield');
    if(val=="custom")
        document.getElementById('customdrinkfield').style.display='block';
    else
     document.getElementById('customdrinkfield').style.display='none';
    }    
  </script>  
  </head>

         <body>
  
      <div class="field">
  
  <!--name field //-->
  <form class="form-request" action="" method="POST" id="myInput>
  <label for="inputName" class="sr-only"></label>
  <input for="name" name="inputName" value="" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" maxlength="16" required autofocus>
 
     <!--location field //-->
  <br>
  <select name="location" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)' required>
   <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Delivery Location</option>
   <option value="deck">Deck</option>
   <option value="grass">Grass</option>
   <option value="poolShallow">Pool shallow</option>
   <option value="poolDeep">Pool Deep</option>
  </select>
  
  <!--drink field //-->
  <br>
  <select name="drink" id="drinkChoice" onchange='checkvalue(this.value);' required> 
   <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Drink Choice</option>
   <option value="Slushie A">Slushie A</option>
   <option value="Sluishie B">Slushie B</option>
   <option value="water">Water</option>
   <option value="custom">Custom</option>
  </select>

  <!--custom field //-->
  <input type="text" name="customdrinkfield" id="customdrinkfield" style='display:none;' placeholder="Custom"/>
  
  </br>
  <!--submit //-->
  <button id="btnRequest" type="submit" formvalidate value="Submit">Request</button>
  </form>
     </div>
       </body>
       </main>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. But the problem is when you are trying to find `drinkChoice` `select element` you are doing it with its `classname` whereas `drinkChoice` is the `id` given to that `element` and you have to use `#drinkChoice` instead of `.drinkChoice`. So your updated `rule statement` should be as below:

```
customdrinkfield: {
  required: function(el) {
    return $(el).closest('form').find('#drinkChoice').val() == 'custom';
                                     //^^this here
  }
}
```

**[Here is the DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2h4tvqhj/2/)**

Few mistakes I found or better to say below is a good practice:

- Keep `javascript` related stuffs below the page, before the `body` ends. It improves performance.
- Its good to have only one `<script type="text/javascript">` and wrap all your `js` code within it. Multiple parts are not needed.
- Keep an eye on your `checkvalue` function. It ain't gonna work properly if you go from bottom to top.

So here's the updated `html`

```
<html lang="en">
    <main>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
            <h1>D D D S </h1>
            <link rel="stylesheet"href="request.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="field">
                <!--name field //-->
                <form class="form-request" action="" method="POST" id="myInput>
                    <label for="inputName" class="sr-only"/>
                    <input for="name" name="inputName" value="" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" maxlength="16" required autofocus/>
                    <!--location field //-->
                    <br/>
                    <select name="location" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)' required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Delivery Location</option>
                        <option value="deck">Deck</option>
                        <option value="grass">Grass</option>
                        <option value="poolShallow">Pool shallow</option>
                        <option value="poolDeep">Pool Deep</option>
                    </select>

                    <!--drink field //-->
                    <br/>
                    <select name="drink" id="drinkChoice" onchange='checkvalue(this.value);' required> 
                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Drink Choice</option>
                        <option value="Slushie A">Slushie A</option>
                        <option value="Sluishie B">Slushie B</option>
                        <option value="water">Water</option>
                        <option value="custom">Custom</option>
                    </select>

                    <!--custom field //-->
                    <input type="text" name="customdrinkfield" id="customdrinkfield" style='display:none;' placeholder="Custom"/>
                    <!--submit //-->
                    <button id="btnRequest" type="submit" formvalidate value="Submit">Request</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <script src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function ($) {
                    $('#myInput').validate({
                        debug: true,
                        rules: {
                            customdrinkfield: {
                                required: function (el) {
                                    return $(el).closest('form').find('#drinkChoice').val() == 'custom'; 
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });         
                function checkvalue(val) {
                    var element=document.getElementById('çustomdrinkfield');
                    if(val=="custom")
                       document.getElementById('customdrinkfield').style.display='block';
                    else
                        document.getElementById('customdrinkfield').style.display='none';
                }               
            </script>       
        </body>
    </main>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for that. Although I think I might have got confused with what I needed. Basically I need anything jQuery, java to check that anything is typed into the custom field if custom is selected above, also thinking I might/should? change to radio buttons for drink choice.

Comment: @dinodc Well that depends on how you choose to design your screen based on user experience.. i.e. with `radio` or `select`.. Other than that the above solution works.. makes it required only if `custom` is selected.. If you could elaborate on what you need exactly or the functionality much deeper, then I could suggest you more..